# Return type is not returning as int when we perform unboxing

Tags: java, types, return, autoboxing, unboxing

I am using autoboxing and unboxing in Java. Return type for Autoboxing is fine. no issues. but for unboxing the return type is coming as Integer instead of int. please find my coding on below and please let me know please

```
package JavaLearning;

public class NumberLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer x=5;                                    // AutoBoxing

        System.out.println(x.getClass().getName());     // Display the type with the package name

        System.out.println(x);                          

        x=x+5;                                          // Unboxing

        System.out.println(x.getClass().getName());     // Display the type with the package name

        System.out.println(x);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Integer
5
java.lang.Integer
10
```

Comment: What is the question? I'm not sure I understand, you seem to have answered yourself: autoboxing is the mechanism at play here.

Comment: you assigned x is Integer object, why do you think it is int

Comment: you have not unboxed dear

Answer (score 1):

It's coming as `Integer` because you are storing the result of `x+5` to `x` which is an `Integer`, so boxing occurs again.

To see that type is an `int` you should print directly the type of the expression `x+5` but you can't do it, since it's unboxed to an `int` and you can't invoke a method on a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` is declared to be `Integer`. So in the line `x = x + 5;` it is automatically reboxed. If you want to avoid it, use `int y = x + 5;`. But remember that you cannot call `.getClass()` on primitive types.

Comment: Thanks dude. Now I got it that where I made the mistake. thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Integer x` keeps the object reference and is never assigned to a primitive.

This should give you a proper unboxing

```
int newX = x + 5;
```

> Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding
>   primitive (int) value is called unboxing. The Java compiler applies
>   unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the
>     corresponding primitive type.
> - Assigned to a variable of the
>     corresponding primitive type.
>
> [**Source**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the type of a variable is fixed. In your example, the type of `x` is   `java.lang.Integer`, and it cannot change into `int`.

The test you are doing is not valid; you'll never see the type of `x` change to anything else than `java.lang.Integer`.

When you do `x = x + 5;`, then a number of things are happening:

1. The `x` on the right side of the `=` is unboxed to `int`
2. The value `5` is added
3. The result of the `+` operation is boxed again into an `Integer` and assigned to `x`